# Best way to keep MongoDB collection schema in external file

Tags: mongodb, schema, mongoose

What is the best way to keep MongoDB collection schema (using mongoose) in external file and access them from main app.js considering n number of schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a separate directory `models`. And have your db models there. If you want you can follow [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Here is what your directory structure can be like.

```
./project_dir
    app.js
    models
    views
    routes
    package.json
```

In models you have files where you have your db models (files where you have your schema).

You can also have a look at this [sample app at github](https://github.com/madhums/nodejs-express-mongoose-demo)